# Can this code block lead to a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory

Can this code block lead to a memory leak?

```
char * foo = new char [20];
read(STDIN_FILENO, foo, 20);
string bar;
bar.reserve(20);
bar = foo;
delete[] foo;
```

I think it can not, as we use `delete[]` to free up chunks of memory. However, object `bar` may make a difference here. Please share your points.

Comment: Please don't try to learn C++ by asking questions on stackoverflow. It will only make everyone miserable, including you. Read a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) instead.

Comment: If any of `string bar;`, `bar = foo` or `bar.reserve(20)` throws, you have a memleak.

Comment: Homework service alert...

Comment: doesn't this belong on code review?

Comment: @Chiel So what? Homework questions are not off-topic or problematic per se, it's just stuff like assignment dumps (too broad) and "Debug plz!" (no MCVE) that needs treatment. But for the aforementioned reasons, not because they are homework.

Comment: @TheWhiteAfrican It could be on code review, but the way it is asked makes it an alright question on SO

Comment: @nwp Remind me to not ask you to mentor anyone.

Comment: @nicomp Why is that? I happen to do [mentoring of sorts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers) and occasionally people actually learn things which makes me happy. SO Q&A is just not the right place for that.

Comment: [Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/594e6e77b0e2f736) with an exception in the read function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any of `string bar;`, `bar.reserve(20)` or `bar = foo` throws, you have a memleak.

You may use some smart pointers to avoid that:

```
auto foo = std::make_unique<char[]>(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need reserve, and if one of the 20 bytes you read from stdin is \0 you will fill only a few bytes.

Here is the correct code:

```
char * foo = new char [20];
read(STDIN_FILENO, foo, 20);
string bar;
bar.assign(foo, 20);
delete[] foo;
```

...you may have problems with an exception on std::string (constructor or assign), but memory exception IMHO should be handled only if you allocate large quantity of memory, because if an allocation of 20 bytes fails most surely you will not be able to properly handle an exception.

If I had to improve your code, both for speed and safety I'll do it this way:

```
char foo[20];
int len = read(STDIN_FILENO, foo, sizeof(foo));
string bar;
if (len > 0)
  bar.assign(foo, len);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jarod42 is correct. You should use smart pointers. However, in order to solve this problem without smart pointers (to understand the theory), try this:

```
char * foo = new char [20];

try{
    read(STDIN_FILENO, foo, 20);
    string bar;
    bar.reserve(20);
    bar = foo;
    deleted=true;
    delete[] foo;
    }
catch (...){
    delete[] foo;
    throw;

}
```

If there is an exception in one of the first lines, the exception will be caught, and foo will still be deleted. However, unless you have a compelling reason not to, you should use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`

Comment: You're speaking a different language.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So sorry. Missed the syntax error with try. I will edit to fix

Comment: Sorry. I have been coding in python lately. I missed the brackets vs colon. Anything else?

Comment: It's better in the sense that it compiles. But it is terrible C++. But I can forgive you for that. Take my un-downvote for your effort to edit.

Comment: I know. This is a quick attempt to demo theory. It certainly could be more elegant

Answer (score 0):

If you know the buffer size at compile time, you should not allocate it with new. Instead, you should allocate it on the stack, or better yet, read directly into your string's buffer after resizing it. That way you ensure maximum efficiency both code wise and otherwise, including separating allocation from actual reading.